# How to configure or test a container with redux-mock-store in 2019?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-mock-store

I configured a container to test with redux-mock-store to the last version and I get some issues. The find() function not works. I ever receive zero nodes and zero length. When I use mount instead to shallow function this works but I get the issues where the redux mapDispatchToProps is not recognized. How I can guarantee that action will be called? I don't wanna test the store but the action function because I use thunk. Is my reasoning right?

My container:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import styles from './Auth.module.css'

import Input from '../../components/UI/Input/Input'
import Button from '../../components/UI/Button/Button'
import Logo from '../../components/UI/Logo/Logo'
import Spinner from '../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner'
import { auth as authAction } from '../../store/actions/index'
import { checkValidity } from '../../shared/utility'

export const Auth = (props) => {

    const [formIsValid, setFormIsValid] = useState(false)
    const [authForm, setAuthForm] = useState({
        email: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'email',
                placeholder: 'Enter your email'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                isEmail: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        password: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'password',
                placeholder: 'Enter your password'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 6
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
    })

    const inputChangeHandler = (event, controlName) => {
        const updatedControls = {
            ...authForm,
            [controlName]: {
                ...authForm[controlName],
                value: event.target.value,
                valid: checkValidity(event.target.value, authForm[controlName].validation),
                touched: true
            }
        }

        let formIsValid = true;
        for (let inputIdentifier in updatedControls) {
            formIsValid = updatedControls[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid
        }

        setAuthForm(updatedControls)
        setFormIsValid(formIsValid)
    }

    const submitHandler = (event, signup) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        props.onAuth(
            authForm.email.value,
            authForm.password.value,
            signup
        )
    }

    const formElementsArray = []
    for (let key in authForm) {
        formElementsArray.push({
            id: key,
            config: authForm[key]
        })
    }

    let formFields = formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
        <Input
            key={formElement.id}
            elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
            elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
            value={formElement.config.value}
            invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
            shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
            touched={formElement.config.touched}
            changed={(event) => inputChangeHandler(event, formElement.id)} />
    ))

    let form = (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={(event) => submitHandler(event, false)}>
                {formFields}
                <Button
                    disabled={!formIsValid}
                    btnType="Default">Log In</Button>
            </form>
            <Button
                clicked={(event) => submitHandler(event, true)}
                disabled={!formIsValid}
                btnType="Link">Sign Up</Button>
        </>
    )
    if (props.loading) {
        form = <Spinner />
    }

    const errorMessage = props.error ? (
        <div>
            <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{props.error}</p>
        </div>
    ) : null;

    let authRedirect = null;
    if (props.isAuthenticated) {
        authRedirect = <Redirect to={'/'} />
    }

    return (
        <main className={styles.Auth}>
            {authRedirect}
            <div className={styles.AuthForm}>
                <h1>Log in to your account</h1>
                <Logo height="3em" />
                {errorMessage}
                {form}
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.auth.loading,
        error: state.auth.error,
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onAuth: (email, password, isSignup) => dispatch(authAction(email, password, isSignup))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Auth)
```

My test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import Auth from './Auth';
import Spinner from '../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner';
import Button from '../../components/UI/Button/Button';
import Input from '../../components/UI/Input/Input';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const setup = () => {
    const props = {
        onAuth: jest.fn()
    }

    const middlewares = [thunk]
    const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
    const initialState = {
        auth: {
            token: null,
            email: null,
            error: null,
            loading: false
        }
    };
    const store = mockStore(initialState);

    const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<Auth store={store} {...props} />).dive();

    return {
        enzymeWrapper,
        props,
        store
    }
}

describe('<Auth />', () => {

    it('should calls onSubmit prop function when form is submitted', () => {
        const { enzymeWrapper: wrapper, props: reduxProps, store } = setup();
        const form = wrapper.find('form');

        form.simulate('submit', {
            preventDefault: () => { }
        });
        expect(wrapper.props().onAuth).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to test the `Auth` class without the connection to store, you need to use the named import and not the default import. PFB the line to add in your test file for importing the Auth component:

```
import { Auth } from './Auth'; // notice the curly braces around the component name
```

Also, with this approach, you need not pass store as props to the component while rendering, and you can pass the actions as mocked functions (which you are already doing for `onAuth` action). Also you can use shallow with this approach.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, this sounds a better way but not work yet. Even that I have removed store prop, get `{ Auth }` and mocked action functions it be with setProps or in the `shallow(<Auth onAuth={jest.fn()} />` this is an undefined prop.

Comment: It works perfectly after I use `expect(reduxProps.onAuth).toHaveBeenCalled();`